# Why td not filling parent tr when freezing row header?

Tags: html, css

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckxv5Lpb/) highlighting my problem.

### The problem

I want to keep the first cell in each row always visible as my table can have numerous columns. To do so add a margin to the parent of the table, and then alter the positioning of the first th with:

```css
.frozen-cnt th{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: auto;
  width: 3em;
}
```

The problem is that when there are few columns, the tr is not completely filled.

We should normally never see any blue. How can we make the tr always fill the table ?

[image]

### Tried:

I though it was because of bootstrap, so I drop it in the fiddle and the problem remains.
I also tried :

```css
.table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

### Simplified example:

Here is a simplified version of the problem, a more complete version is available in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ckxv5Lpb/)

```html
<div class="frozen-cnt">
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <th>th!</th>
  <td>td1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th>th!</th>
  <td>td1</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

```css
table{
  width:100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
tr{
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  background-color:blue;
}
td,th{
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  background-color:yellow;
}
.frozen-cnt th{
  width: 3em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: auto;
}

.frozen-cnt{
  margin-left:3em;
  width: calc( 300px - 3em );
}
div{
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:visible;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in Chrome and Firefox. There is no problem in Chrome but Firefox. I added this to your CSS:

```
.frozen-cnt td {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykhcqg0t/) (even in IE).

Answer (score 0):

#### tl;dr

```
.frozen-cnt tr {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.frozen-cnt tr>* {
    flex:auto;
}
```

#### Long reply

Thanks N'Bayramberdiyev for your reply, it lead me to solution. Settings to 100% works but leads to unbalanced column with more than one td. With your reply I understood that the display of the row is getting broken by the position of the th. I thus force the display of the tr to be flex in row, and balance the space between all td.

Full fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qwgzn76x/)

P.S: not tested in IE